# Suspicious of Khan Academy's answer for a simple tension on a clothesline question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram, statics

This is the question:

> 3 kg of wet clothes are hung on the middle of a clothesline with posts 6ft apart. The clothesline sags down by 3 feet. What is the total tension upon the clothesline?

They give the answer:

> Because there are two anchor points for the clothesline, we can assume
> the horizontal components cancel each other out. The vertical
> component, $30N$ ($F=ma$, using $10\frac{m}{s^2}$ for the gravitational constant)
> should then equal $T\cos 45 + T\cos 45$, or $2T\cos45$ since we have a 45-45-90
> triangle. ($\sin45$ could also be used, remember that cos45 = sin45).
> Solve for T: \begin{aligned}2 * T * \cos\ 45 &= 30\\ T *\cos\ 45 &= 15\\ T* 1/\sqrt{2} &= 15\\ T&= 15\sqrt{2} \end{aligned}

I'm struggling to understand why the answer isn't $30\sqrt{2}$. If you imagine the clothesline as two separate wires with tensions $a$ and $b$ then $a \sin 45 + b \sin 45 $ would equal $30 N$, and if you asked what is the tension in $a$ and $b$ total, the answer would obviously be $Ta + Tb$.  Or put another way, it seems like this formula $- 2T\cos 45 = 30$ -- should be $2\cdot 1/2T \cos 45 = 30$, which gives $T = 30\sqrt{2}$.

But maybe there's something I don't get.

​

Comment: The clothesline (mass neglected) is a continuous string. Tension at every point has to be same. Also if individual tensions were a and b, total upwards tension would  be $asin(45)+bsin(45)$

Comment: I disagree with the close votes. This is a conceptual question.

Answer (score 0):

The tension in each half of the clothesline is $15\sqrt2\text{ N}$.

You don't generally add tensions. Instead, you calculate tension as a function of position. In this case, the tension everywhere in the clothesline is the same, so it's a constant function with a value of $15\sqrt2\text{ N}$ and that's what you report as the answer.

I think you could make a case for reporting tensions as double what they're normally reported as, because of their bidirectional nature. That just isn't the convention used in practice.